# Clickable image with icons in Android

Tags: android, drawable

I need to make this clickable image similar to an imageMap in HTML. I also need to put an icon over the clickable area (in the center, sort of like a map marker), but how do I account for image resizing?

i.e. my image might be 800x600 and the clickable area might be the rectangle covered by 20,20 and 60,40, but these pixels don't actually refer to the same position in the image anymore when it isn't displayed on a pixel perfect fashion.

EDIT: my images are taken from sdcard, not from drawable folders

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what i found in this [link](http://catchthecows.com/?p=113)

> I found myself needing to display an image and have the user tap on
>   different parts of the image to navigate and perform actions.  After
>   sketching out what I needed, it became apparent that what I wanted was
>   something like an HTML map tag, but in an Android view.  A bit more
>   thinking and I decided this would be a useful widget to have
>   available.

**The resulting code:**

> Supports images as drawable or bitmap in layout Allows for a list of
>   area tags in xml Enables use of cut and paste HTML area tags to a
>   resource xml  (ie, the ability to take an HTML map and image and use
>   it with minimal editing) Supports panning if the image is larger than
>   the device screen Supports pinch-zoom Supports callbacks when an area
>   is tapped. Supports showing annotations as bubble text and provide
>   callback if the bubble is tapped The code can be found in [GitHub –
>   Android Image Map](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap)
>
> Update 2 March 2012: Added an option to always resize the image using
>   the original image bits. Certain images, when resized up and down lose
>   a lot of their image quality. Always resizing from the original bits
>   gives the best possible image, but requires extra memory. The tradeoff
>   is now up to you.
>
> Here are some quick notes about the implementation, I’ll make some
>   follow up posts with more details about some of the key areas.
>
> The ease of associating the map with the img matches the ease of doing
>   so in an img tag in HTML.  Just supply the name of the map to use in
>   the layout:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ctc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ctc.android.widget"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.ctc.android.widget.ImageMap  
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/usamap"
        ctc:map="usamap"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> The area map is specified in your project at res/xml/map.xml One
>   difference over HTML maps is that each area must have an id. I went
>   back and forth on this requirement, and I may change the code to allow
>   for areas without id. The code will use the name attribute if present,
>   otherwise it will look for title or alt. The current implementation
>   also requires a name for each area, though this could be changed
>   easily.

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<maps xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <map name="gridmap">
        <area id="@+id/area1001" shape="rect" coords="118,124,219,226" />
        <area id="@+id/area1002" shape="rect" coords="474,374,574,476" />
        <area id="@+id/area1004" shape="rect" coords="710,878,808,980" />
        <area id="@+id/area1005" shape="circle" coords="574,214,74" />
        <area id="@+id/area1006" shape="poly" coords="250,780,250,951,405,951" />
        <area id="@+id/area1007" shape="poly" coords="592,502,592,730,808,730,808,502,709,502,709,603,690,603,690,502" />
    </map>
    <map name="usamap">
        <area id="@+id/area1" shape="poly" coords="230,35,294,38,299,57,299,79,228,79" />
...
     </map>
</maps>
```

> The image itself is placed in res/drawable-nodpi so that the system
>   will not attempt to fit the image to the device based on dpi. This way
>   we are guaranteed that our area coordinates will map properly to the
>   displayed image.
>
> Here is a sample activity that finds the view in the layout and adds
>   an on click handler

```
public class ImageMapTestActivity extends Activity {
    ImageMap mImageMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // find the image map in the view
        mImageMap = (ImageMap)findViewById(R.id.map);

        // add a click handler to react when areas are tapped
        mImageMap.addOnImageMapClickedHandler(new ImageMap.OnImageMapClickedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onImageMapClicked(int id) {
                // when the area is tapped, show the name in a
                // text bubble
                mImageMap.showBubble(id);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBubbleClicked(int id) {
                // react to info bubble for area being tapped
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that but that does not give me the actual position where I should put the icon on the resampled image. It is an interesting solution though.

Comment: Actually I didn't use that but i think when you starting to implement it you will get more idea how its actually work.

Comment: I see the coordinates though.